# Changing UI layout on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Am working on website in which I have to provide a label say label name is 'see in another view', and after clicking on that label my complete UI layout or template should get change(web pages contains various elements like tables, buttons, forms,etc.).

As I am newly learning UI development I genuinely need help. Can anyone suggest me anything that how would I achieve this?Should I maintain two different templates to change layout on one click(but I think it would be difficult to maintain two different templates) or anything else?

Comment: Make the layout with CSS, and switch the used stylesheet according to the selected layout.

Comment: you need to change the entire template or only the colors

Comment: I recommend using Angular https://angular.io/docs

Comment: It would be better if you create two different view here.

Comment: @Ram, I need to change entire template

Comment: Changing the template is not the same as changing the layout. If you keep the same elements but change the order and/or appearance, then you've a layout to change. If you create new elements then you change the template, and you'll need a template ...

Comment: yes you are right, I am sorry for the mistake I need to change layout

Comment: Then switcing the stylesheet would be the simplest way. What you need is a separate stylesheet for the both layouts (and perhaps a third stylesheet for the common proeprties). Then just [disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) the current, and enable a disabled stylesheet for the new layout. This way you can switch the entire layout at once, no need to iterate and change classes or other properties of individual elements.

Comment: The way I achieved this is by writing template code into XML files and populating it with the correct UI, then loading it accordingly when needed, maybe that helps?

Comment: As other said if no new elements were added then by using different stylesheet we could acheive this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to make a label on a form clickable and then once clicked, perform another action afterwards?

Depending on the complexity of your design, you could select all elements and then modify their corresponding styles with JavaScript. Here is a quick example as a visual to convey the idea.

```js
$("label").on("click", function() {
 $("form").addClass("hideme")
  $(".container").removeClass("hideme")
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -99999;
}

label:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
.showme {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<form>
<label>Click ME</label>
<input type="text"></input>
</form>

<div class="container hideme">
<p>I am a new container</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would combat this issue with JavaScript, and clever CSS classes.

Using JavaScript, I would attach an event listener to the input element that the label is attached too. When the label is clicked, it will trigger the input element's events.  A function can be called from this EventListener, which can attach a CSS class to the `<body>` element.

```
document.querySelector('input#input-element-id').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('different-layout') 
})
```

You can then use CSS to apply the different layout and style. For example:

```
.different-layout .title { font-size: 12px; }`
```

However, if the user refreshes their page, they will be reverted back to the original view. To stop this from happening, you can utilise the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) and save and retrieve the currently selected view. You would set the view in localStorage on the same click event that you set the styling. You would retrieve it, then add class, on page load.